# How to use foreach input[type=submit]?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, loops, foreach

In my form there are multiple submit buttons and each submit button should redirect the page to same location but the content changes based on the session variable set. But writing `isset();` for each submit button is difficult. So I am trying to write a loop where foreach input type submit the loop should write the `isset();` function.

My form is like:

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="submit" name="type1" value="type1" > <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="type2" value="type2" >
</form>
```

And I have tried to mix up JQUERY with PHP to achieve this, like:

```
<?php
  echo '<script>
  $("input:submit").each(function(){
  var inputName = $(this).attr("name");' ;
                    
  $inputName = print 'document.write(inputName);';
            
  if(isset($_POST[$inputName])){
    $_SESSION["value"] = $inputName;
    header('Location:somepage.php');
  } 
            
  echo '  });
        </script>';
        
?>
```

But this is not working.

Kindly help me to achieve the loop foreach input which has type as submit.

Comment: You can't write PHP in JavaScript. PHP runs on the server, JS runs on the client.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-do-i-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)

Comment: In the submit button you can put a `formaction` atttribute. It will then submit to that URL instead of the action of the form.

Comment: Your loop is redirecting to the same `somepage.php` for each submit button. I thought you said each button should redirect to a different location.

Comment: @Barmar, I tried achieving my aim mixing jquery and php. Now I am looking on how to achieve this using php only. But I am stuck!!

Comment: @Barmar, yes like the page redirect's to same page but the content changes based on the session variable set. Sorry for that!!

Comment: Why do you give them different names? Why not use the same name but a different value?

Comment: Only one submit button can be clicked and they all have a different value.  Just use an array and get the value.

Comment: is that help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/67959051/13239969

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since only one submit button can be submitted, just use the same name for them all and whatever distinct value you want:

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="submit" name="type" value="type1" > <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="type" value="type2" >
</form>

<?php
        
  if(isset($_POST["type"])){
    $_SESSION["value"] = $_POST["type"];
    header('Location:somepage.php');
  }
```

So `$_SESSION["value"]` will equal `type1` or `type2` based on the submit button value in this scenario.

Comment: This actually worked out!!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I thought that I would need a loop for this but never thought that a simple array would solve my problem.

Thanks again!!

Comment: Why use an array? Only one submit button can be submitted at a time.

Comment: @Barmar    I see what you're saying.  Edited...  I was going down a more complex path at first and then didn't change direction.

Comment: been there, done that.

Answer (score -1):

Use an associative array that lists all the possible submit button names. Check for it and then set the session variable.

```
$redirects = ['type1', 'type2'];

foreach ($redirects as $name) {
    if (isset($_POST[$name])) {
        $_SESSION['value'] = $name;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this would also work. But again here I have to type each and every type in the array, right?

Comment: Yes. You have to provide the list somewhere. You could use the same array when creating the buttons in the HTML.

Answer (score -1):

you can use php script only
example :

```
   <?php
   if(isset($_POST['type'])){
      $a = $_POST['type'];
       foreach($a as $b){
       $c = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9]+/i", "-", $b);
    }
    $type = rtrim($c, '-'); //output is type-num ex type-1
    $_SESSION["value"] = $type;
    if(isset($_SESSION['value'])){
      //  header('Location : page.php');
       }
    }
//cahnge 10 to how many input you need
echo'<form method="POST">';
for ($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++) {
    $name = "type[$x]";
echo'<input type="submit" name="'.$name.'" value="'.$name.'" > <br/>';
}
echo'</form>';
```

Comment: He said he's already doing that, but it's difficult for many different names.

Comment: I am trying to avoid this, like typing for each submit button.